# How to add manually namespace for all the visualforce pages and classes from one org to other org in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there any way to migrate visualforce pages, classes objects and fields with the namespace from one org., to another org.,

Comment: Artifacts having namespace means they are coming from a managed package, so you would need to install same package in other org.

Comment: Only option is doing it manually.